# Adding wsdl Fedex file to c# .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wsdl, fedex

I am trying to get started using FedEx webservice and I downloaded the wsdl file.  I can not figure out how to add this to the project.  MSDN is no help at all.  If I try to "add reference" it will not allow .wsdl files , and if I try to "add service reference" it will also not allow .wsdl files.  I am  trying to just get VS to find the wsdl so that I can start to write SOAP call to the webservice using intellisense.  I have seen the answers to other questions were to simply "add web reference" but that will not allow a wsdl file either.

I know there is a way to convert the .wsdl file into a c# class , but don't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add web reference is just that though. It read the wsdl & generates the stub classes

I've just tried this in VS2010. Saved the WSDL for a java web service to disk. Added Service Reference, then clicked Advanced, then Add Web Reference.

In the box that appears type file:// then click then green arrow & bingo, web service found & added.

Perhaps the WSDL is not valid if Visual Studio won't recognise it?

Comment: Wow... I spent 2 hours trying to figure this out , I was making something Caps that shouldn't have been '_V10 ' instead of '_v10'  , I just figured I was doing it wrong, so I didn't look too hard

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to download the WSDL file, why not give the URL to the WSDL file in the "Add web reference"?? Am I missing something here?

Comment: yea, fedex doesn't do it like that, they make you download it - the url is what I'm used to

Comment: Host this on a local machine and browse to it to generate the schema. Also look at svcutil.exe

Answer (score 0):

Question is very old but I felt adding clearer steps;

- Login to your Fedex Account and download TrackService zip file.
- This is a sample API web application but you just need to find the TrackServiceDefinitions.wsdl file link and copy it.
- Make sure keep that link in the memory.
- Click on the project name in the solution explorer

[image: Solution Explorer]

- Click on Advanced button in Add Service Reference form

[image: Add Service Reference]

- Click on Add Web Reference button in Service Reference Settings

[image: Service Reference settings]

- Paste the wsdl link you copied earlier into URL field and click on the right arrow. Give a Web reference name then click Add Reference button.

[image]

- You should be able to see this web service in your Web References.